# How to trigger scroll event on specific screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below 500px wide, I am enabling behavior that when scrolling past a certain point, a class is added to a nav to make it sticky. My code looks like so:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#query').offset().top,
    distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

        if(scrollTop > distance){
            $("#nav").addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $("#nav").removeClass("sticky");
        }
});
```

I do not want this triggering on every scroll when the browser width is greater than 500px wide. What are the best practices to restrict this event from triggering above 500px browser width?

Im guessing its as simple as:

```
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
   //run above scroll function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache a live reference to window.innerWidth (App.Utils.viewportWidth) and then use that constantly changing value as a boolean to control the flow of execution of your header function (App.Header.watchHeader).

```
var App = window.App || {};

(function($) {

  App.Utils = {

    breakpointMobile: 500,

    viewportWidth: null,

    init: function() {
      $(window).on('load', $.proxy(this.listenViewportResize, this));           
      $(window).on('resize', this.debounce($.proxy(this.listenViewportResize, this), 200, false));   
    },

    // taken from underscore
    debounce: function(func, wait, immediate) {
      var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;
      return function() {
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        timestamp = new Date();
        var later = function() {
          var last = (new Date()) - timestamp;
          if (last < wait) {
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
          } else {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
          }
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        if (!timeout) {
          timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        }
        if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
        return result;
      };
    },

    listenViewportResize: function() {      
      App.Utils.viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

      $(window).trigger('utils:viewportChanged');
    }

  };

  $($.proxy(App.Utils.init, App.Utils));

}(jQuery));



(function($) {

  App.Header = {

    init: function() {
      $(window).on('utils:viewportChanged', $.proxy(this.watchHeader, this));  
    },

    watchHeader: function() {
      if (App.Utils.viewportWidth < App.Utils.breakpointMobile + 'px') {
        // do your mobile thing
      } else {
        // do your desktop thing
      }
    }

  };

  $($.proxy(App.Header.init, App.Header));

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You'll have to adapt to your implementation, but the only real complexity  here is achieving a dynamic reference to window.innerWidth